# How do I change a SharePoint 2013 Foundation Installation to not install/modify the "Default Web Site"

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, installation, iis7

I have a web server, running IIS, with an existing web application running under the "Default Web Site".  When I installed SharePoint 2013 on the same web server, I noticed it modified the existing web.config file under wwwroot, added a few virtual folders directly under the root, moved all applications from an existing application pool to a new SharePoint application pool, took over port 80, and disabled the "Default Web Site".  Is it possible to have SharePoint 2013 Foundation install without modifying the "Default Web Site"?  I would like to specify a virtual directory for SharePoint to install to, but the SharePoint 2013 foundation installation doesn't appear to have many configuration options during the installation process.

[image: Default Web Site]
[image: WWWRoot]

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't the installation of SharePoint that took over your default web site, it was the provisioning of a new web app at port 80 that did it.

To retain your default web site, just keep away from port 80 for your web applications. If you used the farm configuration wizard, you'll need to either skip it or skip the part that provisions the initial web app, and do it manually on a different port.

And you don't want to mess with SharePoint's defaults regarding virtual directories. While it might be possible (I can't say for sure), it's definitely not recommended and will likely cause a mess of problems for you.

Rule of thumb: don't fight SharePoint. You will lose.